# Match Against search not doing exact search?

Tags: mariadb, full-text-search

I'm using MariaDB version 10.2.22 with a InnoDB engine, utf8 charset, it has one column that is indexed FULLTEXT. The table itself is only 4.4 GB with avg row length at 255.  When I do a query such as:

```
    SELECT m.id as id
    FROM 
    table1 m,
    table2 d
    where 
    m.id= d.id AND
    MATCH ([column]) AGAINST ('"CE20-2019"' in boolean mode)
```

I get a "`SQL Error [128] [HY000]:Table handler out of memory`". I suspect that the "-2019" is being searched or not included, I'm not sure, and that the found matches exceeds the memory allowed. The [column] is a "LongText" datatype.

I've tried changing the innodb_buffer_pool_size to 4 GB and then 8 GB, but still get this error.

(System has 24 GB of RAM, not sure if my comfortable changing it to 70% of RAM listed on their documentation found here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb-memory-allocation/), since I'm on version 10.2.22, this innodb_buffer_pool_size variable is suppose to be dynamic so I don't have to restart the MariaDB service to restart Mysqld.

Any ideas what's causing the Table handler out of memory?

Comment: Does the `2019` "word" occurs frequently in the dataset?  (My Answers, below, is predicated on that assumption.)

Comment: Yeah 2019 does appear quite a bit since this OCR files starting from last year and 2019 occurs quite a bit. It also gives me an error when I do a match([column]) against ('"2019"")

Comment: 70% of a 24GB server is still a reasonable setting for a machine that is running essently only the database.

Comment: Consider writing a bug report about `against ('"2019"")`.

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:

As you put the data into the table, change `-` to, say, `_` so that such items will be on "word", not two.  Do a similar change when constructing the `AGAINST` clause.

If necessary, make an extra column with that and do any other cleansing of the data -- Then index that column with `FULLTEXT`, but use the original table for output.

Plan B:

```
MATCH (col) AGAINST ('+CE20' in boolean mode)
AND col LIKE '%CE20-2019%'
```

Or, if you need a regexp to handle a letter/digit before:

```
MATCH (col) AGAINST ('+CE20' in boolean mode)
AND col REGEXP '\\bCE20-2019'
```

(That's for MySQL 8; use `[[:<:]]` instead of `\\b` for other versions.  That is "word boundary" and should eliminate most of the 20 extra rows.)

That will run nearly as fast as the original query *should* have run.

Alas, this requires understanding the incoming data and making programmatic decisions as to how best to construct a fast query.

Note that the use of `+` when `IN BOOLEAN MODE` *may* be the 'right' thing to do for your app.

Comment: Tried Plan B first, originally it worked but when I performed a search on something I know that works and didn't error out before, it produced extra results. For instance, "TC19-23587" originally I would get 4 results, with the new query it produces 24 results. I might have to look at doing option A now.

Comment: @Yodavish - Check those extra 20 results.  Might they have been "XYZTC19-..." or other cases where "%" acts differently than the "word boundary" of Fulltext?  If so, we might be able to devise a `REGEXP` instead of `LIKE`.

Comment: yeah it's OCR text so I think it's just including "[a-z0-9]TC19" or maybe even "[a-zA-z0-9][space] TC19". How could I include a REGEXP?

Comment: @Yodavish - If you _want_ "[a-z0-9]TC19", `FULLTEXT` is not useful.